# Incorrect Output in NSDate dateFromString

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY"];
 NSDate *myTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"07-22-2014"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myTime);
```

I am converting a stored date(currently hardcoded) into `NSDate` format so that I can display it and apply operations on it. But `myTime` is giving wrong output.

```
2013-12-21 18:30:00 +0000
```

whereas I am passing `07-22-2014` as string and expecting me to output `07-22-2014`.
Do I need some formatting apart from setting it right. ? What is the reason of going wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
   NSDate* myTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"07-22-2014"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myTime);
```

Comment: BTW - get rid of the needless `[[NSDate alloc] init]`.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 -(NSString *)dateFormater:(NSDate *)date
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        NSString *strDate=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
        formatter = nil;
        return strDate;
    }
```

use like this..

```
NSString *temp=[self dateFormater:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what is needed. The OP wants to convert a string to a date, not a date to a string.